# bash inject escape sequences to read

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do the following:

```
...$ left=$'\e[D'
...$ read -e -i "prompt${left}" line
```

I'd like to get `prompt` with cursor on `t`, but I get:

```
prompt^[[D
```

any ideas? Seems as if I cannot binding keystrokes with `-i` option

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Comment: Bash just fills readline buffer with the text given with `-i` option, like, it doesn't feed that text to readline. So what you're trying to do is I think not posiible.

Comment: @oguzismail imagine you're designing a TUI (in bash, yes, I know it isn't the best language).One widget is a field entry. You're editing field with readline. you press TAB ('\t') to focus to another field. How do you continue first field editing?

Comment: I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the command line, we can bind the `read` command to a function key :

```
bind '"'$(tput kf5)$'":"read -e -i prompt\n\e[D"'
```

You press `F5` to run `read`

Comment: that's clever, albeit a bit complex for my case

Comment: It's a bit more involved. Ideally, READLINE_LINE and READLINE_POINT should be restored (i.e. injected) programmatically, not by keypress (F5) or sleep (bad practice). Good idea nonetheless

Comment: AFAI can tell, it fails. reads/cursor updates on different processes get desynchronized

Comment: just backspace (delete) p, t dissapears. ENTER and line = promp

Comment: You are right, have you taken a look at this tool : http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html ?

Comment: I look for a similar idea but for the console. I guess that it can be done with a pseudoterminal, but it gets too complicated. Another idea is process substitution: `read -e line < <(echo -n "prompt\033[D"; cat)`, but I can't make it to work

Comment: Agreed, if you use process subs... input cannot go back to tty. If we take a step back, what do you want to achieve in the end ?

Comment: design a TUI forms library fully in bash (labels, entries, buttons...), with forward (TAB)/backward (STAB) navigation, so that when editing an entry you can escape to other focused widget (another entry or button...) and return to the original widget at the same editing state

Answer (score 1):

Just `echo` it.

```
echo -n "prompt${left}"
read -r line
```

Comment: Better to use `printf` than `echo` -- `-n` has explicitly undefined behavior per POSIX, and flip the right runtime flags and `echo -n` will print `-n` followed by a newline.

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm afraid I was too fast acknowledging. What I want is to edit line with a prefix (prompt in this case) with CSI movements applied. Your answer doesn't allow to edit prompt